# JSON + MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, json

I have the following query that checks the relationship between two users:

```
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, followingID FROM following WHERE IdUser = '%d' AND followingID = '%d'", $id, $followingID);
```

I then check the results based on a count of 0 - 1 for the relationship

```
    if (count($result['result'])>0) {

    //the username exists, return error to the iPhone app
    print json_encode(array('following'=>'yes'));

   } else {

    print json_encode(array('following'=>'no'));
  }
```

The problem is, I am using an iOS application to pair with the PHP API.

I was wondering how I would determine the relationship in Objective-C.

If I do this:

```
    if (![json objectForKey:@"error"]) {

        NSLog(@"%@", json);
   }
```

It returns:

```
2013-08-06 21:51:12.025 AppName[1311:c07] {
following = yes;
```

}

Any idea on what my IF condition would be for my iOS app for the relationship for following / not following? Or if I could make my json_encode for my PHP API a simpler return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just check for `following`:

```
NSString *following = [json objectForKey:@"following"];

if ([following isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
    // handle yes
} else if ([following isEqualToString:@"no"]) {
    // handle no
} else {
    NSLog(@"unexpected value for following: %@", following);
}
```

Comment: Or you could use `NSString *following = json[@"following"];`